# Python decoding, base64, nbt, gzip? what is it?

Tags: python, base64, decode

I am trying to get information from a Minecraft AP. From the API you can read players inventories, but it this is what it says: [here is link to pastebin](https://pastebin.com/SdkLBNy7)

I tried to run base64 on it on python, but it gave me an output like this (only a few lines):

```
b'\xad\xa9\xc0d\x85\xe4\xe0\x87`\xcess\x00\x9b]e~c\xea\xaa\xb8\x9a\xa4\xdd\x958"\x8f\x0f\x10\xb9\xea\x9f2v\xdd\xcc#N\xe8x\xb4\xdd\x18\xa9\xee>\xcfM
```

I read a bit about it on their forums, and a few comments said stuff about "base64, gzip, nbt".

Know, I haven't really worked at decoding stuff, etc, and I am trying to understand what it all means.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NBT is a minecraft specific format: [Named Binary Tag](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/NBT_format)

So you get an NBT-File, that is zipped (compressed) in the [gzip format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) and then [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded.

After [base64 decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/python-base64-data-decode) you need to [unzip the gzip format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902540/read-from-a-gzip-file-in-python) to get the NBT.

There's also a [nbt parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414426/nbt-parser-minecraft-mca-file-not-a-gzipped-file-error) in python.

Comment: oh okay, I think I understand then. Thank you!

Comment: So, I am getting the value from an API. Can I just put the entire string into a txt file, or does it need to be a .dat file, and with that .dat file I use the nbt parser?

Comment: It's usually a question about memory usage. If it is small enough, you can do all steps in memory. I actually have no knowledge about Minecraft and nbt, so please check the lib and see usage examples.

Comment: Yeah, I am mostly confused on what steps I have to do, as I am getting that information from an API that changes live. I think I kinda get it if I would have had a .dat file from Minecraft, such as "player.dat". But right now I don't really have that, which makes me really confused haha